# How to make ranger image preview work in tmux

Tags: image, tmux, preview, file-manager

I am a big fan of Ranger (file manager) and I have recently started using tmux which is pretty cool. I found out that when using ranger outside of tmux - then image preview works just fine. I am using Konsole terminal with Archlinux.

Anybody figured out the way to make Ranger's image preview work in Tmux ?

Big thanks/